# Wubi set up and Wifi with no ethernet?

Tags: wireless, networking, wubi

I am extremely new to using Ubuntu.  While I have a basic grasp of scripting for git/linux and scripting for windows, ubuntu scripting isn't super clear for me.

I'm wanting to set up a wifi driver w/o having to install ethernet... wondering if that's even possible?

Do you think there may be a way to download an installer from windows and somehow insert it into the Ubuntu partition?

Really wanting to avoid using Ethernet, it would be a huge headache to resolve, and presumably open a can of worms to start disconnecting the wifi router, which is not actually my own.

Anyways, based on some previous threads, it sounds like I need to try using lspci and lsusb, but I don't really understand those commands or what to expect thereafter.

Any advice for getting wifi on Ubuntu/Wubi partitioned off Windows 7, without ethernet?

Also, I saw a youtube recommending I find out the chipset for my wificard?  Not really sure how to do that offhand? Suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

edit: Worst case scenario, would it be possible to get the driver(if even needed) from win7 to usb stick to Ubuntu?

Comment: What you are suggesting may be very easy or very difficult depending on your wireless chipset. Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Edit your question to add the result and we'll continue.

Comment: Sweet, ok, so:`04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)`

Answer (score 0):

Please download this file on any other computer: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/l/linux-firmware-nonfree/linux-firmware-nonfree_1.14ubuntu1_all.deb Transfer it on a USB drive or similar and drag and drop it to your desktop. Now, from the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

Your wireless should now be working. It may take a reboot.